# (MEncoder) How to resolve librtsp: buffer overflow in rtsp_get error?

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, buffer-overflow, video-encoding, mencoder

I'm trying to use MEncoder to dump an RTSP stream I get. When I try to do the same, I get an error saying "librtsp: buffer overflow in rtsp_get".

The full console output is given below.

```
C:\mplayer-svn-37594>mplayer -dumpstream "rtsp://qa.vibrnet.com:80/mov/video.sav?MAC=00C0021F1116&channel=2&GUID=betauser"
MPlayer Redxii-SVN-r37594-4.9.3 (i686) (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
FFmpeg version: N-77758-g6e24946
Build date: 2016-01-09 00:49:37 EST

Playing rtsp://qa.vibrnet.com:80/mov/video.sav?MAC=00C0021F1116&channel=2&GUID=betauser.
Resolving qa.vibrnet.com for AF_INET...
Connecting to server qa.vibrnet.com[204.x.x.x]: 80...

librtsp: buffer overflow in rtsp_get
```

When I tried to play the stream, I get this error as well. What could be the reason? Help me resolve this one. Thank you!